# Removing the fixture to change light bulb...do I pull, twist

Tags: light-fixture

[image]

I do not know what to do to remove this cover to install new bulbs.I assume you have to pull it down or twist but being afraid to put much force in to it for fear of breaking i dont know what to do. Somebody help me!
Thanks

Comment: Does it have *any* play when you pull or twist or is it rock solid to any of these motions?

Answer (score 3):

If there's no visible screws, then it has to be a twist. Get a ladder you can stand on (like an A-frame) and **gently** try to turn it to the left. Hopefully it moves without a ton of effort.

Good luck!

Comment: Note that it's probably not a true thread situation, but 3 or 4 bumps on the glass that engage slots in the metal housing.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar fixture in my house. The glass has L-shaped slots molded into it. You remove it by turning it counter-clockwise about 60°, and then pulling it gently downwards.

The bumps in the housing tend to bind in the slots, so wiggling the glass up or down might make it easier to turn.